# Integrating Haskell in non-functional projects

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have looking to Haskell questions in SO, and I recovering my university notes on functional programming as a hobby. But I've always wondered how could something done in Haskell get outside Hugs interpreter and integrate with a C#, C++ or Java project. Has anybody done that? How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, first of all, Haskell compiles to machine code, so you don't have to worry about the interpreter bit.

As far as integrating with other languages, your best bet is the [Foreign Function Interface](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/ffi/).

Comment: Haskell compiles to machine code via more sophisticated compilers like GHC.

Answer (score 1):

For integrating with .NET projects, there is also http://haskell.forkio.com/dotnet/

Answer (score 1):

To integrate with other code, you need to use the FFI (as was already said). Usually, you would use GHC (the Glasgow Haskell Compiler) and compile to machine code, rather than use an interpreter like Hugs. (Most "real" projects use GHC instead of Hugs.)

Answer (score -2):

Python has a subset which is pretty much a functional language.

Comment: There are some functional features in Python, but it is definitely *not* a functional language.